Problem with implementation and lifecycle service by red texts. Android studio, what is wrong here？
Problem with implementation and lifecycle service by red texts. It's Android studio. What is wrong here？
I was tried redownload the android studio. And,sdk and jdk can normally display on the CMD.(adb,java -version)

Just click "Sync Now"

And don't screenshot your whole desktop. Protect your own privacy.

@Vincent Can you please post only build.gradle app file alone

@Vincent can you please post the error message you are getting when you try to build the project

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your build.gradle file is in  kotlin dsl.But your code is for groovy dsl.You need to change that to make the project work.Did you copy paste the code from somewhere.
You need to change and use this following lines instead.
For Example
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    kotlin("android.extensions")
}

I have changed for your plugin code.You may need to do the same for dependancies.
